# Routing on NodeJS Express

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, url-routing

I'm developing a server in NodeJS with Express, but the web structure is a little bit complicate (I didn't do it, and I can't change it either).

The flow is something like this:

1. Node server receives a call like `https://localhost/**{id}**`.
2. The ID received is the folder's name where all files (html, js, css,
   etc) are stored. By default, it returns `index.html`.
3. File structure of any web doesn't have a strict logic, means that could be more views at the same level the `index.html` is or in folders, wherever the clients wanted to develop them.

The issue I'm having is how to route the files correctly. Since I'm receiving the ID only when the index it's called, I couldn't figure out how to route links like `<a href="view1.html">View 1</a>` or even the javascript files calls `<script src='scripts/someGreatFunctions.js'></script>` since they could also be in the root or in a folder (even the two things at the same time).

My `server.js` file:

```
const express = require('express');
const https = require('https');
const fs = require('fs');
const app = express();

const config = require('./config');

var webId;

var options = {
  key: fs.readFileSync(config.paths.certificate.key),
  cert: fs.readFileSync(config.paths.certificate.crt),
  requestCert: false,
  rejectUnauthorized: false
};

app.use(function (req, res, next) {
  res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
  res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true");
  res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, HEAD, OPTIONS, POST, PUT");
  res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Accept, Access-Control-Allow-Headers, Access-Control-Request-Headers, Access-Control-Request-Method, Authorization, Content-Type, Origin, X-Requested-With");
  next();
});

app.get('/scripts/:script', function(req, res) {
  res.sendFile(req.params.script, {root: config.paths.webs + webId + '/scripts'});
});

app.get('/:script.js', function(req, res) {
  res.sendFile(req.params.script + '.js', {root: config.paths.webs});
});

// This routes correctly the index
app.get('/:id', function(req, res) {
  webId = req.params.id;
  res.sendFile('index.html', {root: config.paths.webs + webId});
});

// This DID NOT work
app.get('/:id/:page', function(req, res) {
  //Some code here...
});

https.createServer(options, app).listen(443, function() {
  console.log("NodeJS secure server started at port 443");
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I am also in a learning phase. Hope this will help.

```
app.get('/test/:id/:page', function(req, res, next) {
    let id = req.params.id;
    let page = req.params.page;
    console.log('The id: ' + id);
    console.log('The page: ' + page);
});
```

Comment: I've tried, but not working. The first part of the URL, where you put `/test/`is _dinamic_ for me, so it isn't the same. Thanks for you reply!

Answer (score 1):

I finally got the answer. Seems like it's very important the order in which `gets` are declared. Also, I used a regular expression to make it a little more generic.

```
/**
 * HTTP GET for files (.html, .js, etc.) from another folder level
 */
app.get('/:id/:folder/:file', function(req, res) {    
  if (typeof(webId) === undefined) {
    webId = req.params.id; 
  }
  let folder = req.params.folder;
  let file = req.params.file;

  res.sendFile(file, {root: config.paths.webs + webId + '/' + folder});
});

/**
 * HTTP GET for .js files from the base path
 */
app.get(/\/\w+.\b(js)/, function(req, res) {
  let lastBar = req.url.lastIndexOf('/');
  let script = req.url.substr(lastBar);

  res.sendFile(script, {root: config.paths.webs});
});

/**
 * HTTP GET for index page
 */
app.get('/:id', function(req, res) {
  webId = req.params.id;
  res.sendFile('index.html', {root: config.paths.webs + webId});
});

/**
 * HTTP GET for view from base path
 */
app.get('/:id/:page', function(req, res) {
  if (typeof(webId) === undefined) {
    webId = req.params.id; 
  }
  let page = req.params.page;

  res.sendFile(page, {root: config.paths.webs + webId});
});
```